# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type 'IO b' with actual type bool

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO b' with actual type `Bool'
In the expression:
  upCheck
    ["########", "#11xxx3#", "#xx2xx3", "#002xx3", ....] 2 [2, 3, 4]
In the expression:
  do { s <- readFile "projekt-board.txt";
       let content = lines s;
       printTable content;
       printHelp;
       .... }
In an equation for `gameFunc':
    gameFunc
      = do { s <- readFile "projekt-board.txt";
             let content = ...;
             printTable content;
             .... }
```

With the definition for `gameFunc`:

```
gameFunc = do
  s <- readFile "projekt-board.txt"
  let content = lines s
  printTable content
  printHelp
  upCheck ["########","#11xxx3#","#xx2xx3","#002xx3","#7x2x44#"] 2 [2,3,4]
```

and function `upCheck`:

```
upCheck :: [[Char]] -> Int -> [Int] -> Bool
upCheck tableArr number posArr = do
  --posArr saadakse findBlock funktsiooniga
  let arv = findVIndex (findVertIndex tableArr number)
  let str = tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)
  if ((posArr !! 0) == 1)
  then False
  else if arv == (-1)
    then False
    else if isHorizontal str number
      then False
      else if (tableArr !! ((posArr !! 0)-1)) !! arv /= 'x'
        then False
        else True
```

So basically what is happening here is that `upCheck` is a function to check whether some conditions are matched and when I call it out the same way from ghci as i call it out from the function `gameFunc`, i will get a result `True`. However, if I call it out from the function `gameFunc` I get an error described above. Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function `gameFunc` uses a do expression which is syntactical sugar for a *monad* (in this case the `IO` monad). You can turn any non-monadic result into a monadic one by using the `return` function:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

So you can rewrite your `gameFunc` to (see last line):

```
gameFunc = do
  s <- readFile "projekt-board.txt"
  let content = lines s
  printTable content
  printHelp
  return $ upCheck ["########","#11xxx3#","#xx2xx3","#002xx3","#7x2x44#"] 2 [2,3,4]
```

Now `gameFunc` has the type `IO Bool`. You can use `gameFunc` in other monadic environment like:

```
main = do
    b <- gameFunc
    print b
```

in order to print the result of `gameFunc`.

Comment: As far as I understand the situation, yes. I think however you better get some insights in Monads because everything that has to do with IO in Haskell requires some knowledge of Monads.